# Typed recursive element

Tags: types, recursion

1. Need to define XSD element that has some attributes and can hold list of itself

This is the type definition:

```
<xs:complexType name="t_TestCase" >
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element type="t_TestCase" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

This is the element based on the type:

3. BUT - when adding attribute to the type - it seems that it is not valid anymore. (the sequence tag is invalid)

Advise please?

Tx

Answer (score 0):

Use a complex type like so:

```
  <xs:element name="t_TestCase">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="t_TestCase"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="att1"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Edit: my first answer sucked

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that the top node is an element rather than ComplexType...
What i do want is to define everything as ComplexType and then assign this to an element. Is that possible?

Comment: The problem is that if you're allowing children of the complex type "t_TestCase" to be nested within themselves, under what tag are they nested?  You have to name an element somewhere.